# Critical Power Action doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, gnome, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I run Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my HP Probook 430 G4 laptop and I have a little problem. The Gnome Power Manager application lets us select a critical power action but that doesn't seems to work. I have enabled hibernation, I also tested all options like sleep, hibernate and hybrid sleep and all works fine, system recovers without problem. No matter what I select the process of suspendig/shutting down starts but it fails to do so and I end up back at the login screen. I also edited the /etc/UPower/UPower.conf file and changed the critical action but even that gets ignored and fails to do it. Have anyone experienced a problem like this, any solutions?

Comment: After another failed auto hibernate I found this in the syslog:

Feb 23 13:18:10 peter-laptop upowerd[1569]: (upowerd:1569): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1701 was not found when attempting to remove it